# Create empty dictionaries from a list of strings

Tags: python, django

If I have a list of strings like

```
variations = ['color','size','quantity']
```

Is it someway possible to convert the strings in a list to empty dictionaries?
The result I want is

```
color  = {}
size = {}
quantity = {}
```

Comment: What advantage do you see if you can get this to happen? I would say that what you want is this: `variations = {'color':{}, 'size':{}, 'quantity':{} }`. Then to address each `dict` you just need to access: `variations['color']` etc.

Comment: `var_dict = {var: {} for var in variations}`

Comment: Different codes have different requirements based on the scenario. I want empty dictionaries to be created from a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky but you can use `locals()`. First you need to create a dictionary that includes key value pairs as your variable name and its value.

**1st way**

```
variations = ['color','size','quantity']

d = {} #temporary dictionary
for var in variations:
    d[var] = {}

locals().update(d) # update your local variables.

print(color) # should print {}
```

However, for this type of requirement, using namespaces is a better idea than this. The idea is similar, but more safer.

**Better way**

```
from types import SimpleNamespace    

variations = ['color','size','quantity']

d = {} #temporary dictionary
for var in variations:
    d[var] = {}
    
n = SimpleNamespace(**d) #create namespace with those variable,value pairs
print(n.color)
```

Comment: the `locals` approach won't work within a function.

Comment: the problem with the code is that you are creating dictionaries inside dictionary whereas I don't want that.

Comment: that dictionary is temporary. you wont need it after locals().update(d) command. After that you can reach your variables via its names (not with dictionary). Did not you try to run the code? Or, you are just commenting by looking at the code? With this way you create variables from list of strings. (dictionary inside dictionary is just a temporary thing)

Comment: @acushner that s why I also mentioned the better way.